# relation between two tables manyToOne odoo mobile

Tags: odoo-mobile

i need to show the person name
actually i show the id of person

```
 public void onViewBind(View view, Cursor cursor, ODataRow row) {
 OControls.setText(view, R.id.name, row.getString("person_id"));
  }
```

there are a relation manyToOne between class (sanction) and (ResPartner)

in this class(sanction)
i put this code

```
public class Sanction extends OModel {
public static final String TAG = Sanction.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.odoo.Etudiant";
 OColumn person_id = new OColumn("name", ResPartner.class, 
 OColumn.RelationType.ManyToOne);
```

he shows me the id of person but i need to show his name
what can i do ?

Comment: "Person_id": [
            81,
            "JackZ        ],

format of Json

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String[] rows = row.getString("person_id").spit(",");  
if(rows != null){
   if(rows[1] != null){
      String name = rows[1];
   }
}
```

Hope this will work for you